# Using Robocopy in Powershell to move folders

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to move folders/files over a certain age from one location to another

The Robocopy part works on its own, but the script as a whole doesnt

here is what I've got

```
foreach  ($i in Get-Item C:\ -Recurse)
{
    if ($i.CreationTime -lt ($(Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)))
    {
        robocopy "C:\" "C:\Old Files" /Z /S /MOVE 
    }
}
```

This doesnt do anything in Powershell

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is confusing. Are you trying to get top level folders in C:\ that are older than a certain date and if so move them?

Comment: Hi Jeffery, basically i have a mapped drive with lots of folders and files of varying age. I am trying to move them into a seperate folder in order to go through them and delete ones I dont need

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do. You need to start thinking in the PowerShell mode. This is a oneline command.

PS C:> dir | where {$*.PSIscontainer -AND ($*.Creationtime -lt (Get-Date).AddMOnths(-6))} | foreach {
 robocopy $_.fullname c:\oldfiles /Z /S /Move
}

Although you could also use the Move-Item cmdlet.

Comment: The above script gives errors, will look into it further, to see if I can work this out

Comment: I have modified the above script but get an error - Get-ChildItem -Recurse c:\test | where ($.Creationtime -lt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)) | ForEach-Object { robocopy "c:\test" "c:\old" /Z /S }                                                                                                     "$.creationtime is not a recognized cmdlet"

Comment: $_ refers to the current object in the pipe: Get-ChildItem -Recurse c:\test | where {$_.Creationtime -lt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)} | ForEach-Object { robocopy "c:\test" "c:\old" /Z /S }